# Naming with count number in Matlab

Tags: matlab, naming

```
FileName = fullfile('C:\Users\User\Desktop\1cm circle cropped 0.27',sprintf('circle_cropped_%d.jpg',count));
```

The code I use would give file name
(circle_cropped_1.jpg, circle_cropped_2.jpg, circle_cropped_3.jpg.........)

How to name the images with "circle_cropped_001.jpg, circle_cropped_002.jpg, circle_cropped_003.jpg.........................."

And how to move the counting number? to be "001_circle_cropped.jpg, 002_circle_cropped.jpg, 003_circle_cropped.jpg......................."

Comment: Did you read [the documentation to `sprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)? You should be able to figure out your answer based on that.

Answer (score 3):

```
FileName = fullfile('C:\Users\User\Desktop\1cm circle cropped 0.27',sprintf('%03d_circle_cropped.jpg',count));
```

Assuming you want a total field width of 3. If you want more, specify `%04d` or `%05d` etc, the prefix `0` there ensures the desired string width is filled by padding with zeros.